# Creating a transition pattern library

Tags: web-app, design-patterns, animation, transitions, library

I am looking to compile and apply a list of transitions/animations across a web application.

Does anyone have any good examples of any existing transition pattern libraries out there?

I know the [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/richinteraction/) one obviously and have also come across this [YUI Gallery](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/).

I suppose I'm interested in finding a good approach to organizing the transitions in a way that is easy to scan/consume. I'm not sure the examples I mentioned achieve this.

Comment: http://www.ui-transitions.com/

Comment: Nice question! Could you tell us in what type of context this transition will be used, and It'll be easier to answer the question.

Comment: Ah I had seen this site before Vitaly but had forgotten about it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Benny, it's a large business applications. There are many transitions and many contexts. It's hard for me to be really specific about it. A lot of the transitions would be standard enough. It's not the transition types that concern me at this point, it's devising an easy to read reference library that concerns me at the moment.

Answer (score 6):

[Meaningful Transitions - Motion Graphics in the User Interface](http://www.ui-transitions.com/) has some really nice examples of transitions along with detailed descriptions of how they can be used to enhance the user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried http://sixux.com/tagged/transition/page/3 ?
It uses video on Vimeo to show transitions.
Also http://capptivate.co  for IOS/mobile